# How can I set up a tkinter GUI for my web scraping program?

Tags: tkinter

I have a function:

```
def atime_scrape(asia_times):
    
    # create dataframe 
    atime = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

    # pass url list to URL column
    atime['URL'] = asia_times

    # create dictionaries 
    atime_date = {}
    atime_title = {}
    atime_auth = {}
    atime_type = {}
    atime_corpus = {}
    atime_summary = {}
    atime_category = {}

    # iterate through URL column to scrape data
    for i in atime['URL']:

        # general
        req = Request(i, headers=headers)    # make the request 
        page = urlopen(req).read()           # get the response
        soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')       # parse the response into a bs object

        # date
        for x in soup.findAll('meta', {'property':'article:published_time'}):  
            atime_date[i] = x['content'].split('T',1)[0]

        # title
        for x in soup.findAll('meta', {'property':'og:title'}):
            atime_title[i] = x['content']

        # author 
        for x in soup.findAll('meta',  {'name':'twitter:data1'}):
            atime_auth[i] = x['content']

        # type
        for x in soup.findAll('meta', {'property':'og:type'}):
            atime_type[i] = x['content']

        # text         
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
        config = Config()
        config.browser_user_agent = user_agent
        page = Article(i, config=config)
        page.download()
        page.parse()
        atime_corpus[i] = page.text.replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\n',' ')

         # category   
        for k, v in url_category.items():
            if str(i) == str(k):
                atime_category[i] = v

    # map data by URL to dataframe
    atime['Article Date'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_date)
    atime['Article Title'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_title)
    atime['Author'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_auth)
    atime['Source'] = 'Asia Times'
    atime['Type'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_type)
    atime['Text'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_corpus)
    atime['Category'] = atime['URL'].map(atime_category)

    return atime.to_csv(testCSV.csv)
```

My program currently takes a CSV or XLSX file of URLs to news articles, sorts them by source, passes them to their respective scrape functions, and outputs a CSV/XLSX file with author, title, date, text, etc.

I would like to create a GUI in tkinter that takes this CSV or EXCEL file of URLs as a text input, and then have a button that, when clicked, executes this function so that the output is a CSV/XLSX file exported to my machine.

Any thoughts/help on this would be GREATLY appreciated.  I am happy to share my program with anyone as well.  It works excellently as is, but it currently requires the user to manually change the input file of URLs

Comment: This question is way too broad for stackoverflow. If you have a specific question on how `tkinter` works, I will be happy to try to answer it.

Comment: Make a button with a callback function: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading
from tkinter import filedialog

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Asian News Scraper")
gui.geometry("600x300")

label = Label(gui, text="Select File: ")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

def scraper(asian_time):
    # Your Scraper Here
    pass

def run_scrape():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Choose A File", filetypes=(("CSV Files", "*.csv"),("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"))
    theader = threading.Thread(target=scraper, args=(file))
    theader.start()

button = Label(gui, text="Scrape / Format", command=run_scrape)

gui.mainloop()
```

### Hope that answered your question

> NoobScience

Comment: And Yes I would like this program. Does it have a github?